# Azure Log Analytics Agent not installed on VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics, azure-security

I setup Security Center in Azure for one of my subscriptions.

I set Automatic Provisioning "On" and expect that every VM created under that subscription has Log Analytics Agent installed by default(that is what I understand from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-enable-data-collection#enable-automatic-provisioning-of-the-log-analytics-agent-)).

However, the agent is not installed as expected when I create a new VM. Does anyone have an idea why that might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Use of the security center requires an upgrade of your subscription. Initialy there is a 30 day free trail.

There are 3 things you could check:

- Has the subscription been upgrade with a free trail that has expired
- Has the upgrade of the subscription been deactivated
- Are the VM's created within the expected subscription

Comment: Hi Shiraz, I've already upgraded it to Standard Tier for Security Center and all the VMs created are under the Standard Tier subscription.

Comment: Even I see this message under Security "All set! All of your Azure subscriptions have automatic agent installation enabled"

Comment: Which OS / OS version do your VM's run?

Comment: You could also check the list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-troubleshooting-guide#mon-agent

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Security-Center/Azure-Security-Center-Monitoring-Agent-Deployment-Options/ba-p/817520) states that it can take up to 16 hours to get agent installed.